# Twitter bootstrap tabs suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

It was working fine until a while ago. I did not change anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <title></title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>


 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <header>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#elevenam" aria-controls="elevenam" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">11:00 AM</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#fourpm" aria-controls="fourpm" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">4:00 PM</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#ninepm" aria-controls="ninepm" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">9:00 PM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="elevenam">
            <div class="row">
                <?php include_once 'elevenam.php'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="fourpm">
            <div class="row">
                    <?php include_once 'fourpm.php'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="ninepm">
            <div class="row">
                    <?php include_once 'ninepm.php'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong with twitter bootstrap??
my js used to be link

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

from their site but it stopped working so i tried the downloaded one and it still doesn't work.

I notice in their demo, it wasn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

because

```
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20integri ty=%22sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7`
```

is no more public. Upload a file on your server and load the css from there.

Comment: I changed the CSS and JS to downloaded version now. My tabs are still not working.

Comment: code please?  I will like to see..update the code then

Comment: Oh... inside my elevenam.php
I had too many ")" in my if statement like

if ())
{}

Comment: @JohannaCristineDy issue resolved? that means it didnt have to do anything with this script?

Comment: because there was an error in the included php file. the rest of the HTML (the one whit the script tags) did not run anymore.